# PHP call function within private function in class method

Tags: php, class

I try call Test3 function, but returned this error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function".

Here is an example:

```
class Test {
    public Test1(){
        return $this->Test2();
    }

    private Test2(){
        $a = 0;
        return Test3($a);

        function Test3($b){
            $b++;
            return $b;
        }
    }
}
```

How to call Test3 function ?

Comment: Why are you nesting functions like this in the first place? Make Test3 a separate method in your class, and then you can call it as $this->Test3() and your won't run into problems like this

Comment: There is no use for nested php functions, they could be treated as a side effect of the parser.

Comment: `public Test1(){` what language is this?

Comment: Thanks Mark Baker, and thanks to all. Your tip worked. But it is possible in this format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From PHP DOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

Use Closures

```
$test = new Test();
echo $test->Test1();
```

Modified Class

```
class Test {

    public function Test1() {
        return $this->Test2();
    }

    private function Test2() {
        $a = 0;

        $Test3 = function ($b) {
            $b ++;
            return $b;
        };

        return $Test3($a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you wanted a `closure` or if your 'inner' function was a typo.

If it was meant to be a separate method then the below is the correct syntax:

```
class Test 
{

  public function Test1() 
  {
    return $this->Test2();
  }

  private function Test2() 
  {
    $a = 0;
    return $this->Test3($a)
  }

  public function Test3($b)
  {
    $b++
    return $b;
  }

}
```